# Deploy python project between multiple machine

Tags: python, git, server, pycharm

I'm creating a Python project to do some data gathering and analysis.

I would like to run my project on a cloud-hosted VM, but do my development in PyCharm on my mac. What is the recommended tool for this workflow, or is this workflow totally not recommended?

One idea that I have is to use a git server (hosted on my virtual machine as opposed to somewhere public-facing like github) and then push my project there. I have only used github for hosting a git server, however, so I'm not sure if this is worth the headache.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Developing locally and pushing to production is the standard way to do things. What else would you do? And why would you want to host a "git server"?

Comment: To clarify, my question is, what's the best way to go between the two environments? Do I just have to SFTP the files from my local machine to my production machine? What is the easiest and most professional way to run my locally developed code on a cloud-hosted VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a building a scraper or some sort of data gathering tool I would recommend to look into serverless/lambda.

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/

Or if you are dead set on trying to run it on a cloud vm without any headache and it's a small app you should look into heroku they have a great free tier where you can run your data gathering app for 0$ per month.

You can also run it on lambda for 0$ per month.

For good serverless integration I would recommend to try python zappa. https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa which would basically run set up your serverless for you which will most likely also cost you 0$ dollars per month because on an awesome free tier.

Hope this helps.